# Undefined is not a function (jQuery add/remove class)

Tags: jquery, function, class

I'm making a simple swap button which doesn't seem to work.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<a onclick="paid(123);" class="no" id="123"></a>
<a onclick="paid(124);" class="yes" id="124"></a>
<a onclick="paid(125);" class="no" id="125"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function paid(currentId) {

if (document.getElementById(currentId).hasClass("no")) {
    document.getElementById(currentId).removeClass( 'no' ); 
    document.getElementById(currentId).addClass( 'yes' );   
}

else if (document.getElementById(currentId).hasClass("yes")) {
    document.getElementById(currentId).removeClass( 'yes' );    
    document.getElementById(currentId).addClass( 'no' );    
}

}
</script>
```

Am I missing something obvious here? :)

Comment: Try to avoid defining ids starting with numbers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not using jQuery to select those elements, so they don't have the `hasClass`, `removeClass` and `addClass` methods. They are just DOM elements. Use this instead:

```
function paid(currentId) {

// Select the element using jQuery
var $elem = $("#"+currentId);

if ($elem.hasClass("no")) {
    $elem.removeClass( 'no' ); 
    $elem.addClass( 'yes' );   
}

else if ($elem.hasClass("yes")) {
    $elem.removeClass( 'yes' );    
    $elem.addClass( 'no' );    
}

}
```

Additionally, you should not use `onclick` attributes. You should use the jQuery syntax instead:

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("no")) {
        $(this).removeClass( 'no' ); 
        $(this).addClass( 'yes' );   
    }

    else if ($(this).hasClass("yes")) {
        $(this).removeClass( 'yes' );    
        $(this).addClass( 'no' );    
    }
});
```

Finally, (trying to be nice here!) you should read a good jQuery tutorial as it seems you haven't fully grasped the techniques required to use the library.

Comment: THANKS! Works great :) I will accept the answer within 10 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating function `paid()`, you can use jQuery like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('a').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('yes');
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('no');
    })
})
```

This will bind click event to Anchor tag and toggle Classes.

Answer (score 0):

A pure javascript solution will be like this:

**HTML**

```
<a onclick="paid(this);" class="no" id="123">Link1</a>
<a onclick="paid(this);" class="yes" id="124">Link1</a>
<a onclick="paid(this);" class="no" id="125">Link1</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
function paid(current) {
   if(current.className == "no") {
      current.className = 'yes';
   } else if(current.className == "yes") {
      current.className = 'no';
   }
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m4S9C/2/)